# Routing for CakePHP i18n

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to internationalize all the pages on my CakePHP site with the following format:

- /en/about
- /zh/about (for Chinese version)
- etc.

I already have all the routes defined at router.php, eg.

```php
Router::connect('/about/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'about'));
Router::connect('/login/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
// etc...
```

How do I make it so that /language/ prefix is automatically applied to all the Router::connect()s?

At CakePHP library's router.php, there is an example for the similar routing and is given as such:

```
 Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/:id', 
                 array(), array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'lang' => '[a-z]{2}'));
```

This however, only works for the default routing type (eg. /pages/about/) and not a specially defined one like /about for my example.

In other words, it would work when user visits /zh/pages/about but not when user visits /zh/about

Any suggestions or do I have to manually rewrite all my Router::connect()s to include lang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Router::connect('/:lang/:controller', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{2}'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{2}'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{2}'));
```